# Is there any thread pool for Sun/Oracle CORBA implementation and how to configure it?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, corba, orb

I would like to know **how many client requests my CORBA server can handle at same time** :

1. Does the server creates a new thread for each new client request ?
2. Is there any thread pool ?
3. What is the default thread pool size ?
4. What happens if we reach the max size ? Does the new threads wait in a queue ?
5. What is the idle time for inactive threads (threads which have already been used for a client) in the pool ?
6. Are we able configure those parameters (pool size & idle time) ?

I've done a lot of research but I didn't find real answers to those questions for the Sun/Oracle official CORBA implementation (JDK). In the Oracle Documentation ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abegz/index.html)) we can see this  :
***-Djava.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.appserv.naming.S1ASCtxFactory
-Dcom.sun.appserv.iiop.orbconnections=value***

=> I am not sure about what really this parameter is, also this parameter may not be compatible with all JVMs, and its default value is "one".

I know that for RMI there is a "*sun.rmi.transport.tcp.maxConnectionThreads*" parameter for changing default thread pool size (which is already "unlimited"). The inactive threads idle time is 1 minute... RMI is inspired by CORBA, so maybe Sun/Oracle put the same parameters for both of them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the server creates a new thread for each new client request ?

Sun CORBA implementation have Thread Pool.

2. Is there any thread pool ?

Yes. Sun CORBA implementation have Thread Pool.

3. What is the default thread pool size ?

You don't need to worry about this.

4. What happens if we reach the max size ? Does the new threads wait in a queue ?

I use JacORB their default size is 100 and in previous version (JacORB 2.2.2) the client get killed all the time that server reach this size.

5. What is the idle time for inactive threads (threads which have already been used for a client) in the pool ?

Don't know. I think the implementation uses the Thread Pool.

6. Are we able configure those parameters (pool size & idle time) ?

Don't know. I think you not suposed to worry about it.

** I think JacORB is better than SUN's implementation. It has CORBA 2.3.

** Warning: You need to worry about Local ThreadLocal. Because when the client's request ends the Thread goes back to Thread Pool, so you can get some data in a new request ThreadLocal.